# Windows Shell Script Issue - Response always invalid

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

Below is a .bat file with the code for a tic-tac-toe game for a class I am in. No matter what I change, I'm always greeted with "Invalid move. Please try again!" when entering a box location (eg, A1). The validation occurs in :ValidateResponse, starting in line 273. Can anyone see what I have done wrong causing this response? Thanks.

```
@ECHO off

REM ***************************************************************************
REM
REM Script Name: TicTacToe.bat
REM Author: 
REM Date:
REM
REM Description: This is a Windows shell script implementation of the popular
REM child's game called "Tic-Tac-Toe".
REM
REM ***************************************************************************


REM ****** Script Initialization Section ******

REM Set the color scheme to yellow on black
COLOR 0E

REM Display the name of the game in the Windows command console's title bar
TITLE = T I C - T A C - T O E

REM Clear the display
CLS


REM ****** Main Processing Section ******

REM This label is called whenever the game needs to be restarted
:StartOver

REM Global variables used throughout the script
SET Player=X
SET Winner=None
SET /A NoMoves = 0
SET /A NoMoves = 0

REM Reset all the squares on the game board to show blanks
CALL :InitializeBlanks

REM Display the Welcome screen and prompt the players for instructions
CALL :Welcome

REM Process the player's instruction
IF /I "%reply%" == "" CLS & GOTO :StartOver
IF /I %reply% == Play CLS & CALL :Play
IF /I %reply% == Quit CLS & GOTO :EOF
IF /I %reply% == Help CLS & CALL :Help
IF /I %reply% == About CLS & CALL :About
GOTO :StartOver

GOTO :EOF


REM ****** Main Processing Section ******

REM Reset all squares on the game board to blanks
:InitializeBlanks

  SET A1=
  SET A2=
  SET A3=

  SET B1=
  SET B2=
  SET B3=

  SET C1=
  SET C2=
  SET C3=

GOTO :EOF

REM Display the Welcome screen when called
:Welcome

  REM Clear the display
  CLS

  REM Add 8 blanks lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,8) DO ECHO.

  ECHO                 W E L C O M E  T O  T I C - T A C - T O E
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO                         Windows shell script style!

  REM Add 9 blanks lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,9) DO ECHO.

  REM Display a menu of options
  ECHO Options: [Play] [Quit] [Help] [About]
  ECHO.

  REM Prompt the player to make a selection
  SET /p reply=Enter selection:

GOTO :EOF

REM Display the game board
:DisplayBoard

  REM Clear the display
  CLS

  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO     T I C - T A C - T O E
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO         1     2     3
  ECHO.                                     Rules:
  ECHO.
  ECHO            ^|     ^|                 1. Player X always goes first.
  ECHO A        %A1%  ^|   %A2%  ^|  %A3%
  ECHO       _____^|_____^|_____            2. To make a move enter the
  ECHO            ^|     ^|                    coordinates of the appropriate
  ECHO B        %B1%  ^|   %B2%  ^|  %B3%                  square.
  ECHO       _____^|_____^|_____
  ECHO            ^|     ^|                 3. Remember to switch turns when
  ECHO C        %C1%  ^|   %C2%  ^|  %C3%                  instructed by the game.
  ECHO            ^|     ^|
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO Player %player%'s turn:
  ECHO.

GOTO :EOF

REM Display the help screen when called
:HELP

  REM Clear the display
  CLS

  REM Add 5 blank lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO ECHO.

  ECHO                           HELP INSTRUCTIONS
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO  This is a text-based implementation of the TIC-TAC-TOE game. In this game
  ECHO  the computer controls the action. Player X always goes first. The game
  ECHO  tells each player when it is his turn. When prompted to take a turn players
  ECHO  must type the coordinates of the square into which they wish to place their
  ECHO  marker (the X or O character). For example, to place a marker in the
  ECHO  upper left hand box, players would enter A1.
  ECHO.
  ECHO  The game tracks the progress of each game and will automatically determine
  ECHO  when a game has been won, lost, or tied.

  REM Add 6 blank lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,6) DO ECHO.

  REM Make the player press a key to continue
  PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:About

  REM Clear the display
  CLS

  REM Add 7 blank lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,7) DO ECHO.

  ECHO                        About The TIC TAC TOE GAME
  ECHO.
  ECHO                        Written by
  ECHO.
  ECHO                    Jerry Lee Ford, Jr.
  ECHO.
  ECHO                 ------------------------
  ECHO.
  ECHO                      Copyright 2003

  REM Add 7 blank lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,7) DO ECHO.

  REM Make the player press a key to continue
  PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

REM This procedure controls the actual play of the game
:Play

  REM If player X has won then find out if a new game should be started
  IF "%Winner%"=="X" (
    CALL :DisplayGameResults
    REM Make the player press a key to continue
    PAUSE
    GOTO :StartOver
  )

  REM If player O has won then find out if a new game should be started
  IF "%Winner%"=="O" (
    CALL :DisplayGameResults
    REM Make the player press a key to continue
    PAUSE
    GOTO :StartOver
  )

  REM If the players tied find out if a new game should be started
  IF "%Winner%"=="Nobody" (
    CALL :DisplayGameResults
    REM Make the player press a key to continue
    PAUSE
    GOTO :StartOver
  )

  REM display the game board
  CALL :DisplayBoard

  REM Collect current player's selection
  SET /P response=Select a box:

  REM Validate the specified selection
  CALL :ValidateResponse

  REM If the selection is valid
  IF %ValidMove%==True (

    REM Add 1 to the total number of valid selections made in the game
    SET /A NoMoves = NoMoves += 1

    REM Associate the player's selection with the right square
    CALL :FillInSquare

  REM If the player's selection is invalid
  ) ELSE (

      REM Clear the display
      CLS

      REM Add 11 blank lines to the display
      FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,11) DO ECHO.

      ECHO                        Invalid move. Please try again!

      REM Add 11 blank lines to the display
      FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,11) DO ECHO.

      REM Make the player press a key to continue
      PAUSE
  )

  REM If a total of 9 valid selections have been made the board is full
  IF %NoMoves% == 9 (
    SET Winner=Nobody
  ) ELSE (
    CALL :SeeIfWon
  )

  REM Its now time to switch players
  IF %ValidMove%==True (
    IF "%player%"=="X" (
      SET Player=O
    ) ELSE (
      SET Player=X
    )
  )

  REM Loop back to the beginning and keep playing
  GOTO :Play

GOTO :EOF

REM Ensure that the selection supplied by the player is valid
:ValidateResponse

  REM By default assume a valid selection was made
  SET ValidMove=True

  REM Hitting enter without entering a selection is invalid
  IF /I %response% == "" (
    SET ValidMove=False
    GOTO :EOF
  )

  REM Ensure that a valid square was specified (A1-A3, B1-B3 & C1 - C3)
  IF /I NOT %response%==A1 (
    IF /I NOT %response%==A2 (
      IF /I NOT %response%==A3 (
        IF /I NOT %response%==B1 (
          IF /I NOT %response%==B2 (
            IF /I NOT %response%==B3 (
              IF /I NOT %response%==C1 (
                IF /I NOT %response%==C2 (
                  IF /I NOT %response%==C3 (
                    SET ValidMove=False
                    GOTO :EOF
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )

  REM Previously selected squares are invalid
  IF /I %response%==A1 (
    IF NOT "%A1%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==A2 (
    IF NOT "%A2%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==A3 (
    IF NOT "%A3%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==B1 (
    IF NOT "%B1%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==B2 (
    IF NOT "%B2%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==B3 (
    IF NOT "%B3%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==C1 (
    IF NOT "%C1%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==C2 (
    IF NOT "%C2%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )
  IF /I %response%==C3 (
    IF NOT "%C3%"==" " (
      SET ValidMove=False
    )
  )

GOTO :EOF

REM Associate the player's selection with the appropriate square
:FillInSquare

  IF /I %response%==A1 SET A1=%player%
  IF /I %response%==A2 SET A2=%player%
  IF /I %response%==A3 SET A3=%player%
  IF /I %response%==B1 SET B1=%player%
  IF /I %response%==B2 SET B2=%player%
  IF /I %response%==B3 SET B3=%player%
  IF /I %response%==C1 SET C1=%player%
  IF /I %response%==C2 SET C2=%player%
  IF /I %response%==C3 SET C3=%player%

Goto :EOF

REM Display the results of the game
:DisplayGameResults

  REM Clear the display
  CLS

  REM Set the default message to indicate a tie
  SET messagetext=Tie - No Winner

  REM If either player won set a variable containing a custom message
  IF "%Winner%"=="X" SET messagetext=Player X has won!!!
  IF "%Winner%"=="O" SET messagetext=Player O has won!!!

  REM Add 5 blank lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO ECHO.

  REM Display the final board and display a message indicating game results
  ECHO               ^|     ^|
  ECHO            %A1%  ^|  %A2%  ^|  %A3%                E N D  O F  G A M E
  ECHO          _____^|_____^|_____
  ECHO               ^|     ^|
  ECHO            %B1%  ^|  %B2%  ^|  %B3%                 %messagetext%
  ECHO          _____^|_____^|_____
  ECHO               ^|     ^|
  ECHO            %C1%  ^|  %C2%  ^|  %C3%
  ECHO               ^|     ^|

  REM Add 9 blank lines to the display
  FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,9) DO ECHO.

GOTO :EOF


REM Check up, down, & diagonally to see if the player has won
:SeeIfWon

  REM Check across
  IF /I "%A1%"=="%player%"  (
    IF /I "%A2%"=="%player%"  (
      IF /I "%A3%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )
  IF /I "%B1%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%B2%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%B3%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )
  IF /I "%C1%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%C2%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%C3%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )

  REM Check diagonally
  IF /I "%A1%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%B2%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%C3%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )
  IF /I "%A3%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%B2%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%C1%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )

  REM Check up and down
  IF /I "%A1%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%B1%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%C1%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )
  IF /I "%A2%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%B2%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%C2%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )
  IF /I "%A3%"=="%player%" (
    IF /I "%B3%"=="%player%" (
      IF /I "%C3%"=="%player%" (SET Winner=%player%)
    )
  )

GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have faulty logic in :ValidateResponse.  I only answered the question you asked.  This will allow you to move on to the next problem.  Keep at it!

```
REM Ensure that a valid square was specified (A1-A3, B1-B3 & C1 - C3)
IF /I %response%==A1 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==A2 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==A3 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==B1 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==B2 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==B3 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==C1 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==C2 GOTO :ContinueValidating
IF /I %response%==C3 GOTO :ContinueValidating
SET ValidMove=False
GOTO :EOF

:ContinueValidating
```

Then you also need to change all of the lines below that like the one below to change " " to "" because the variable is not initialized to a space.

```
IF NOT "%A1%"==" " (
```

to

```
IF NOT "%A1%"=="" (
```

Comment: Thank you, RGuggisberg. This fixed my issue.